# Spring Conditional SpEL cannot be parsed

Tags: spring, spring-el

I want to parse `#{environment.containsProperty('PROP')?"${PROP}"+'/':''}` which get a property from environment and then add a slash, but it complains with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PROP' in value...
```

Why did it to get `PROP` when it doesn't exists? BTW, When I set the `PROP` in environment then it can be parsed as expected, so strange.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `${}` expression will be parsed first but it can't find the `PROP` in environment then it throws an exception. I need to add a default value to the `${}` expression to prevent it from complaining an error: just change `${PROP}` to `${PROP:}` and then things goes correctlly.